# py2exe and setting up setup.py to get its target from argv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, argv

I'm trying to create an executable from a .py file, and if I do things *exactly* as the py2exe tutorial says, it works. I put `setup(console=["thingyIdLikeToDo.py"])` in my setup.py file, then type `python setup.py py2exe` into my console, and it works.

BUT. This means that whenever I want to make another python file into an executable, I have to go open and edit setup.py. And I'd rather do something else:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from sys import argv
import py2exe

setup(console=[argv[1]])
##This was originally setup(console=["MyTargetFile.py"]) and it DOES work that way
```

And then type in `python setup.py MyTargetFile.py py2exe`. On account of it being `invalid command name 'MyTargetFile.py'`

I've also tried it by changing the order, making it `python setup.py py2exe MyTargetFile.py` and changing the `argv[1]` to `argv[2]`. I get the exact same error message.

I mean, I DO have a functioning way to make my .py files into .exe files, but I'm really annoyed that something that seems like it ought to be such a simple change is't working. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into trouble because `setup` is using `sys.argv`.  If you change your call to `setup(console = [sys.argv.pop(1)]` I believe you will stop stepping on distutils' toes and things should go smoothly.